# OpenID authentication in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, openid

I am a neophyte with Ruby on Rails but I've created a couple of small apps. Anyway, I'm really interested in OpenID and I would like to implement OpenID authentication and maybe some Sreg stuff in a Rails app. All of the research that I have done has come up with articles that are out of date or just don't work for me. Since I'm so new to Rails I'm having difficulty debugging the issues so...

What is the best way to implement OpenId in Rails?

Comment: Have you watched Ryan Bates' excellent [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/68-openid-authentication) on OpenID Authentication?

Comment: I can recommend AuthLogic for OpenID: [http://www.binarylogic.com/2008/11/21/tutorial-using-openid-with-authlogic/](http://www.binarylogic.com/2008/11/21/tutorial-using-openid-with-authlogic/)

Comment: Check out this: http://github.com/shripadk/authlogic_openid_selector_example A complete app using authlogic-openid with jquery selector and auto-registration. Cheers :)

Comment: I've been working on [GlitterGallery](https://github.com/sarupbanskota/GlitterGallery). I remember struggling with old docs and had blogged about the route I took to make OpenID login work. You might be interested to look it up [here](http://thirstyforcola.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/setting-up-openid-on-rails/). I'm not sure if there's anything better available now, but I'll be coming back and I'll update the post accordingly; cheers!