# How do I create a Stack Overflow-like registration process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, single-sign-on

I am wondering how I can build the registration process like we have in Stack Overflow, where a user can login using one of several already existing accounts? I would prefer using Rails as a technology platform.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenID authentication in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254/openid-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?
http://testingauth.heroku.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you need, but the devise module, available on github, makes it very easy to build a authentication system in a rails application.

For authorization, another great module is called "cancan". You might need that too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki). There are a few [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth) describing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) gem to implement openId auth. Also, it possible to extend your existing user auth systems. See great screencast about this at railscast: [OmniAuth Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1)